# How to concaternate JSX in react to build up ListItems for List component

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, jsx

Object (props.errors):

```
'name' : [
     'The name field is required',
     'The name should be a string'
],
'email' : [
     'Please enter valid email'
 ]
```

Trying to loop over to get a list of all the errors:

```
for (const index in props.errors) {

    const listItems = props.errors[index].map((error, i) =>
        <li key={i}>{error}</li>
    ); 

}

const list = <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
```

How can I concatenate the ListItems when Im looping over each index within the object? I keep overwriting the const with the last value where I want to add to it?

Also, listItems returns undefindex for building the list, i only need to build the list if there are errors in my object.

Any help with how to loop over this and build up the JSX by concatenation would be appreiacted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to map first over the props.errors values and then over each of the values as those are arrays:

```
export const List = () => {
  const errors = {
    name: ['The name field is required', 'The name should be a string'],
    email: ['Please enter valid email'],
  };

  return Object.values(errors).map(values => {
    return values.map(error => <li key={error}>{error}</li>);
  });
};
```

`flatMap` can be used instead of the first `map`, but React already flattens the list for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in React, you can do this without using any loops at all, then you won't accidentally overwrite things.

```
const obj = {
  name: ["The name field is required", "The name should be a string"],
  email: ["Please enter valid email"],
};

Object.values(obj)
  .map((fieldErrors) => fieldErrors.map((error) => <li key={error}>{error}</li>))
  .flat();
```

Note that using an array index for the `key` prop is generally bad practise, so I've used the error string instead.